# Convert array to Horizontal in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following result array in ci3 :

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'Months' => string 'January' (length=7)
      'Operations' => string '6' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'Months' => string 'February' (length=8)
      'Operations' => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'Months' => string 'March' (length=5)
      'Operations' => string '7' (length=1)
```

I want to display the above (or any derived array) in the following horizontal form:

```
Months     January February March
Operations 6       3        7
```

Right now I'm using the following code to display the table in Vertical form :

```
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Month</th>
                    <th>Operations</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php if ($months): ?>
                <?php foreach ($months as $result): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $result['Months']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $result['Operations']; ?></td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </tbody>
 </table>
```

I have converted my array to this form using array_map :

```
$converted = array_map(null, ...$months);

array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'January' (length=7)
      1 => string 'February' (length=8)
      2 => string 'March' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '6' (length=1)
      1 => string '3' (length=1)
      2 => string '7' (length=1)
```

But how to iterate in order to get the desired result ?

Comment: Loop over the array once, output the month into tables cells. Loop over the array a second time, output the operation into tables cells. Wrap each loop into a `tr`. Resp. with your modified array, loop over [0] first, then over [1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this (not tested):

```
<table>

<tbody>

<?php if ($months): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Months</td>
    <?php foreach ($months as $key => $result): ?>
            <td><?php echo $result['Months']; ?></td>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Operations</td>
        <?php foreach ($months as $key => $result): ?>
            <td><?php echo $result['Operations']; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tr>
<?php endif;?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks , works perfect . So the solution is to iterate on each sub key  of the returned array with for each , no need to transpose . I was trying many different solutions that my head got stuck .  The only change I made is to convert the first td for months as th to use as headings  . Thanks again!!

Comment: Yeah, i left out the headings part, since the are not "real" headings, but that's just semantics :D